# Rendering only polygons inside the view boundries: Google Maps Android

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a few clickable polygons as a ArrayList. Is there a way to render polygons that are inside the view boundaries, i.e. visible only at the zoom level? Rather than rendering all of them.

Answer (score 3):

you can add polygons to the map with visibile off and make them visibility on according to google map camera changes.

```
Polygon polygon = map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
     .add(new LatLng(0, 0), new LatLng(0, 5), new LatLng(3, 5), new LatLng(0, 0))
     .strokeColor(Color.RED)
     .fillColor(Color.BLUE)
     .visibility(false);
```

Add camera change listener to GoogleMap instance.

```
googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
            if (cameraPosition.zoom > 12) { // Your zoom level to show polygon
                polygon.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

You can implement additional cases if you need as CameraPosition has more data apart the zoom level. Hope it helped :)

**EDIT** 
To improve handling of many poligons, you could put all your polygons in arraylist and after the camera change, inspect which polygon should be shown:

```
List<Polygon> polygons = new ArrayList<>();
polygons.add(map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
     .add(new LatLng(0, 0), new LatLng(0, 5), new LatLng(3, 5), new LatLng(0, 0))
     .strokeColor(Color.RED)
     .fillColor(Color.BLUE)
     .visibility(false)); //Repeat for as many as you have
```

In camera change listener:

```
if (cameraPosition.zoom > 12) { // Your required zoom level to show polygons
    LatLngBounds latLngBounds = googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
    for (Polygon polygon : polygons) {
        for (LatLng latLng : polygon.getPoints()) {
            if (latLngBounds.contains(latLng)) {
                polygon.setVisible(true);
                break; //Needed if only one polygon can be visible at a time, remove if several can be visible at a time
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE** I think this should work, but I did not test this, hope it helped :)

Comment: This is helpful. But seems more 'hardcoded' for 100s of polygons. Is there any alternative you know of?

Comment: Updated my answer, happy coding :)

Comment: Did you check, whether it makes a difference with regard to performance to reduce the number of polygons to the visible ones? I would assume that the maps API also has some optimization, which avoids spending time on "drawing" invisible polygons. Or for which other reasons do you want to reduce the number of polygons?

Comment: I didnt check it on code, but i think performance may reduce using this method. Im not sure whether google optimizes that or not, but my guess is that they do not